# Set default value with type Union

Tags: python, typechecking, mypy

I want to use type checking using mypy. One input argument to a function accepts either a single `int` or a `List[int]`.

I could use `x: Union[int, List[int]]`, however, what is the correct syntax to set a default value of `10`, if the input argument is a single `int`?

`x: Union[int = 10, List[int]]` is not working.

Comment: I don't understand `"set a default value of 10, if the input argument is a single int"`. If you receive an input argument why would you need a default value? Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default value is not part of the type hint. It goes *after* the type hint, same as for a non-union type:

```
x: Union[int, List[int]] = 10
```

Note the divergence in formatting from PEP-8 convention: whereas default values are usually given without spaces surrounding the `=` (i.e. as `x=10`), this is no longer true when they go after type hints according to [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: @Andi How would that work conceptually? How could an argument have more than one default value?

Comment: My comment was nonsense. Deleted.